# Order of conditions are effecting radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a test page where users can configure there planter.
Calculation etc works fine. But when the radio buttons are used the order of conditions are effecting them.

When Bottom no is selected user should not be able to select feet of wheels > OK
When Bottom yes is selected user should not be able to select feet of wheels > OK

But feet or wheels can not be selected at the same time.
So when wheels yes is selected and then feet yes selected > wheels has to be set to no > OK

But the other way around when feet yes is selected and the wheels yes the script is unable (due to order of conditions?) to set feet to no?

Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculatie()
{
// very much code

// Totaalprijs met of zonder pootjes
if(document.getElementById('feet_no').checked)
{
    document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value = (document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value);
}
else if(document.getElementById('feet_yes').checked)
{
    document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value = ((document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value * 1) + (document.getElementsByName('kosten_pootjes')[0].value * 1)).toFixed( 2 );
    document.getElementById('wheel_no').checked = true;
}

// Totaalprijs met of zonder wieltjes
if(document.getElementById('wheel_no').checked)
{
    document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value = (document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value);
}
else if(document.getElementById('wheel_yes').checked)
{
    document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value = ((document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value * 1) + (document.getElementsByName('kosten_wieltjes')[0].value * 1)).toFixed( 2 );
    document.getElementById('feet_no').checked = true;
}
}
</script>

<tr>
    <td>Bottom</td>
    <td>No <input type="radio" name="bottom" onChange="calculatie()"
    onfocus="document.getElementById('bottom').style.display='block';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='none';"
    onblur="document.getElementById('bottom').style.display='none';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='block';"
    value="no" id="bottom_no" checked="checked">

    <input type="radio" name="bottom" onChange="calculatie()"
    onfocus="document.getElementById('bottom').style.display='block';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='none';"
    onblur="document.getElementById('bottom').style.display='none';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='block';"
    value="yes" id="bottom_yes" > Yes</td>

    <td><div id="dim_top">Dim from top <input type="text" name="bottom_dim" size="2" onChange="calculatie()"
    onfocus="document.getElementById('bottom_dim').style.display='block';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='none';"
    onblur="document.getElementById('bottom_dim').style.display='none';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='block';"
    value="" /> cm </div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Feet</td>
    <td>No <input type="radio" name="feet" onChange="calculatie()"
    onfocus="document.getElementById('feet').style.display='block';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='none';"
    onblur="document.getElementById('feet').style.display='none';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='block';"
    value="no" id="feet_no" checked="checked">

    <input type="radio" name="feet" onChange="calculatie()"
    onfocus="document.getElementById('feet').style.display='block';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='none';"
    onblur="document.getElementById('feet').style.display='none';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='block';"
    value="yes" id="feet_yes" > Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>wheel</td>
    <td>No <input type="radio" name="wheel" onChange="calculatie()"
    onfocus="document.getElementById('wheel').style.display='block';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='none';"
    onblur="document.getElementById('wheel').style.display='none';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='block';"
    value="no" id="wheel_no" checked="checked">

    <input type="radio" name="wheel" onChange="calculatie()"
    onfocus="document.getElementById('wheel').style.display='block';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='none';"
    onblur="document.getElementById('wheel').style.display='none';document.getElementById('basis').style.display='block';"
    value="yes" id="wheel_yes" > Yes</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

http://torza.nl/leon2.php

Comment: Where is `calculatie()` called from? Have you tried putting a click handler on the Feet-Yes and Wheel-Yes radio buttons specifically to uncheck each other?

Comment: Bottom "no" and "yes", both seems to be same per your question

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script and it should work. Made a slight change in it,

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculatie()
{
// very much code

// Totaalprijs met of zonder pootjes
if(document.getElementById('feet_no').checked)
{
    document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value = (document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value);
}
else if(document.getElementById('feet_yes').checked && document.getElementById('wheel_yes').checked)
{
    document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value = ((document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value * 1) + (document.getElementsByName('kosten_pootjes')[0].value * 1)).toFixed( 2 );
    document.getElementById('wheel_no').checked = true;
}

// Totaalprijs met of zonder wieltjes
if(document.getElementById('wheel_no').checked)
{
    document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value = (document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value);
}
else if(document.getElementById('wheel_yes').checked)
{
    document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value = ((document.getElementsByName('kosten_inkoop')[0].value * 1) + (document.getElementsByName('kosten_wieltjes')[0].value * 1)).toFixed( 2 );
    document.getElementById('feet_no').checked = true;
}
}
</script>
```

The order of the if conditions is creating the problem. The radio button is switched when "Wheel Yes" is clicked, but due to the if condition its reverting back.